# RewriteEngine: Query in URL ist not correct working. Maybe Regex is wrong?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url like this:

```
index.php?lang=de&menu=products&sub1=heat&sub2=M123
```

Only the field "lang" is mandatory, so my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(de|at|ch|it|nl)/?(.*)/?(.*)/?(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&menu=$2&sub1=$3&sub2=$4
```

When I read the $_GET I get the followed code...but I want to get filled all variables

```
[lang] => at
[menu] => products/heat/M123
[sub1] => 
[sub2] =>
```

It's my first experience with regex and rewriteengine..sorry fot this maybe stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, using your same replace string:

```
^(de|at|ch|it|nl)(?:/([^/]*))?(?:/([^/]*))?(?:/([^/]*))?$
```

So:

```
RewriteRule ^(de|at|ch|it|nl)(?:/([^/]*))?(?:/([^/]*))?(?:/([^/]*))?$ index.php?lang=$1&menu=$2&sub1=$3&sub2=$4
```

[Working on RegExr](http://regexr.com?37a66)

---

**Explanation**

`.*` is greedy, and since none of the characters after the first `.*` must be matched (`/?` and the remaining `.*` can all happily match nothing) it immediately matches the rest of the string and all the other groups end up as 0 length matches.

Often problems are fixed by making a `.*` lazy - `.*?`, but in this case (I found out through failed testing) the lazy quantifier will still match to the end of the string because it would appear it needs something concrete to match against, and apparently matching an optional `/` isn't enough to take precedence.

So to solve this I replace `/?.*` with `(?:/([^/]*))?`.

`(?: .... )` just means don't capture this group (as $1 $2 etc..)

So ignoring that you have `(/([^/]*))?` for each group.

Each group is optional, and must match a `/` followed by 0-many `non-/` characters. This way you can be sure the the * isn't going to be greedy and consume the next group.

A slightly shorter regex that also works (my original one) but is slightly hard to explain is:

```
^(de|at|ch|it|nl)(?:/(.*?))?(?:/(.*?))?(?:/(.*?))?$
```

Comment: It works....but when I do this: /de/products/heat  <---without "/" at the end, the site couldn't be found! only when I add the slash. Is this another workaraound in the regex or has something to to with the rewrite engine?

Comment: ...and also when I do this /de/products or this /de/products/ the page couldn't be found.